# Design decisions for singleton services managing ConcurrentHashMap of server endpoint configs

Tags: java, tomcat, singleton, concurrenthashmap, threadpoolexecutor

I have a singleton `ServerConfigs` that contains a `static ConcurrentHashMap` member of `ServerConfig` (url, port, number of connections, ...).

The singleton has two 'getServer' methods: 

1) returns a single server configuration

2)  returns the whole map

The singleton also manages these configurations by keeping track of the number of connections each server has attached to it by the by iterating an integer (member of ServerConfig)  every time the getServer methods are called.  It also exposes a releaseFor(ServerConfig) (can be the ID, not necessarily the obj itself) and releaseAll() methods to decrement the connection counts in the map.

I have a `Worker` interface whose abstract impl utilizes a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (that is contained in another singleton class [`ThreadPool`] and shared across the app) by submitting `CallableClient`s to it (which are constructed based on the getServer methods).  The abstract Worker will be extended by many impls that represent various work types of work.  A single session will have many instances of Worker impls submitting tasks to the central `ThreadPool` wrapper holding a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

A) I'm at peace with the directive to use singletons.

B) Yes, this approach is inherently flawed since a single app instance using this code will only get a myopic view of the actual number of connections to the ServerConfig endpoints, since there are other app instances of this app and other apps accessing them.  The endpoints are not JMX friendly.

I need some help in determining if:

1) The `ConcurrentHashMap` is the correct choice to hold the `ServerConfigs` due to fact that several threads may be accessing it for both reads and writes

2) should the methods that expose the map be synchronized?

3) should the ServerConfig member holding number of connections to the endpoint represented here be another type than int?  should its getter/setters be synchronized?

4) would returning deep copies of `ServerConfig` that are separated from the map be a better idea, since their management is centralized to the ServerConfigs singleton anyway?

Furthermore, there will be a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor used to monitor the servers every few minutes to update ServerConfigs map - another few threads accessing and updating the map.

Comment: You should synchronize the `ServerConfig` objects. Maybe this server configuration should be managed in a database instead.

Comment: ServerConfig objects are in the map.  How do I synchronize objects; isn't synchronize for blocks and methods?  I've mentioned that I am considering synchronizing getServer(s) methods in the ServerConfigs singleton, that contains the map.